# How to start thin process at system boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Debian flavor linux system. I am using thin web server to get live status of call in my application. This process gets started, when I use /etc/init.d/thin start. I used update-rc.d -f thin defaults to make thin process to be started at system boot. After adding the entry, I rebooted the system but thin process not getting started. I checked apache2 and it gets started properly at system boot. My thin script in init.d is as follows,

```
DAEMON=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/thin
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/init.d/thin
CONFIG_PATH=/etc/thin           

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0      

case "$1" in
start)                        
    $DAEMON start --all $CONFIG_PATH
    ;;                      
stop)                         
    $DAEMON stop --all $CONFIG_PATH
    ;;                      
restart)                      
    $DAEMON restart --all $CONFIG_PATH
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

My configuration file in /etc/thin is as follows.

user_status.yml

```
 --- 
 chdir: /FMS/src/FMS-Frontend
 environment: production
 address: localhost              
 port: 5000                      
 timeout: 30
 log: log/thin.log               
 pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid          
 max_conns: 1024
 max_persistent_conns: 512
 require: []

 wait: 30                        
 servers: 1
 rackup: user_status.ru
 threaded: true                  
 daemonize: false
```

Comment: Isn't this a question for http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com?

Comment: did you chmod your script to 755?

Answer (score 1):

You need a wrapper for 'thin'.
See https://rvm.io/integration/init-d.
The wrapper path then needs substituting for DAEMON in the init.d script.
I keep forgetting this and it has cost a good few hours!
Now I've checked it out, as root, enter the two commands

```
    rvm wrapper current bootup thin
    which bootup_thin
```

The first creates the wrapper, and the second gives the path to it.
Edit the DAEMON line in /etc/init.d/thin to use this path, and finish off with

```
    systemctl daemon-reload
    service thin restart
```

I have assumed a multi-user installation of rvm, also you have to enter root
with

```
    su -
```

to get the rvm environment right.